# How to receive incoming calls on landline and mobile phone at the same time

Tags: wireless-networking, bluetooth, voip, phone

**Current situation**

- a fixed landline for phone
- just one number: 123-456789
- handled by one DECT base station with three phones
- one mobile (Windows) smartphone with its own mobile number, having wifi, bluetooth, 3G etc

**Needed**

- forwarding of incoming calls to the mobile phone
- while at the same time the DECT set keeps working
- the call is not forwarded, because that would mean the DECT phones won't ring anymore
- It's acceptable that this only works within reach of the Wifi station

**Example**

Someone calls to 123-456789, and the three DECT phones start ringing. At the same time - somehow magically - the mobile phone starts ringing too, and can answer the call. To an outsider it would seem as if the mobile phones acts like one of the DECT phones.

**Possible solutions**

I'm thinking of a device that is connected to the phone line, like the DECT base station, which connects to the mobile phone somehow. This could be wifi or voip. I'm afraid bluetooth will not work well, because of its limited reach.

I'm thinking of a "device", but that is my Y in this [XY](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) situation. Other options, and other ways of looking at this problem are welcome.

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question. Questions about electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones are off-topic, except insofar as they interface with your computer, See [On Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: If you put a device, as for example a Raspberry Pi running Asterisk, you can have the DECT base with the 3 terminals and a mobile phone using SIP over wifi ringing at the same time. The drwaback: You have to learn about Asterisk, raspberry pi,etc.

Comment: @DavidPostill - I'm looking for a solution, not for a device, although it will probably involve a device, which is probably a computer.

Comment: @jcbermu - that is certainly an option, although rather complicated. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: This can be done easily with Google Voice, but will require a third phone number.  Basically google voice has the feature to forward to multiple phone numbers at the same time.  Caller dials Google Voice number and Google voice can forward to landline and mobile at the same time.  Be careful if either of the forward to lines has voicemail tho.

Comment: @jcbermu - we're going with asterisk. So if you want the points, make it an answer!

Comment: @Tyson - yes I know, I just found out many voip companies offer something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it:

Put a device, for example a Raspberry Pi running Asterisk.

The fixed line can be connected to the DECT base and to an ATA with FXO port like [this](http://www.grandstream.com/products/gateways-and-atas/analog-telephone-adaptors/product/handytone-503), to convert it to VoIP.

The mobile phone will use wifi and a softphone as [Zoiper](http://www.zoiper.com/en/voip-softphone/download/zoiper3) or [Media5-fone](http://www.media5corp.com/products/softclients-and-provisioning/media5-fone/) to connect to Asterisk using SIP.

When you receive a call you can make it ring at the same time on DECT and mobile.

There are a lot of ways to install Asterisk on Raspberry Pi. I haven't used  [Incredible PBX](http://incrediblepbx.com/) but I know that is a complete solution with a graphical interface for configuration and maintenance.